# Can we use local variable which is declared data type as TIMESTAMP inside a cursor SQL function?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures

I have scenario to declare some local variable(CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME) of data type as "TIMESTAMP" and local variable(CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME) I want use it inside a cursor to check some condition in WHERE clause.

Here is the example :

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS LOCAL_VARIABLE_NOT_ABLE_TO_ACCESS;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION LOCAL_VARIABLE_NOT_ABLE_TO_ACCESS(USERINFORMATION VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS TIMESTAMP
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN        
        DECLARE CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME TIMESTAMP;

        SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME FROM DUAL ;


                DECLARE DATA_LIST CURSOR FOR (SELECT COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2,COLUMN_3 FROM  TABLE_1 WHERE COLUMN_10 > CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME);
                 /*
            some logic 
                 */  
   RETURN 1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
COMMIT;
```

After executing this query am getting some error as

> Error CODE: 1064
>   MySQL SERVER VERSION FOR the RIGHT syntax TO USE near 'DECLARE DATA_LIST CURSOR FOR (SELECT COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2,COLUMN_3 FROM  TABLE_1 WH' AT line 10

Can someone explain me how to use local variable inside a cursor?  Will it possible to use local variable inside a CURSOR?

Comment: DECLARE should be defined before `BEGIN`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried that also and got same error.  No luck !!

Comment: Which MYSQL version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can use local variable inside function or Cursor for MYSQL.

Check below code.

at time of declaring CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME variable we can set default time for it.

```
            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS LOCAL_VARIABLE_NOT_ABLE_TO_ACCESS;
            DELIMITER $$
            CREATE FUNCTION LOCAL_VARIABLE_NOT_ABLE_TO_ACCESS(USERINFORMATION VARCHAR(50)) 
            RETURNS TIMESTAMP
            NOT DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN        
                    DECLARE CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;       
                    DECLARE DATA_LIST CURSOR FOR (SELECT COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2,COLUMN_3 FROM  TABLE_1 WHERE COLUMN_3 >
                    CURRENT_SYSTEM_TIME);
                     /*     some logic              */  
               RETURN 1;
            END$$
            DELIMITER ;
            COMMIT;
```

Comment: `CURSOR FOR (SELECT ... )` should probably be `CURSOR FOR SELECT ...`.

Comment: Am using MySql version is : 5.7.11. I ran the above , still am getting same error.

Comment: @Vitthal Muguli  first check with this.DECLARE DATA_LIST CURSOR FOR  SELECT COLUMN_1  FROM TABLE_1 . Code is working fine.